# Class name of type parameters in java?

Tags: java

Assuming T as a class type parameter, why cannot I use T.class

I was writing a function that download a page and parses it according to a passed class.
For parsing, I use another function whose signature is : `ParseObject::parse(Class<T> classname)`

```
<T> void downloadParse(){
  ParseObject obj;
  obj.parse(T.class); //<--- why compiler error here?? (whereas something like Integer.class is allowed)
}
```

Comment: short answer: 'type erasure'. Google can do the rest :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Java generics are implemented via [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). They can only be used for compile time checking. After compiliation, the object gets changed to the lowest common object. (In this case Object.class).

The compiled bytecode has no idea what T is.

If you want access to the class, you need to change the method to:

```
<T> void downloadParse(Class<T> cls){
  ParserObject obj;
  obj.parse(cls);
}
```

Comment: TOO QUICK!! Thanks!! you beat google man :) Do not understand the answer 100%, will google more. btw I have done the same thing as suggested. Only I needed to pass the 'cls' parameter around some functions and store it in a class variable in my actual program. (felt weird on doing that)

Comment: It is kind of weird, but that's the only way to do it. If Java ever gets reified generics, it'll make life much, much easier.

Comment: There's no much sense in using this though. Simply use `Class<?>` for the same effect. It only makes sense if you need to enforce some type, e.g. `<T extends Comparable<?>> void dp(Class<T> cls)`. A good rule of thump for generics: try to avoid them as long as possible ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) is the villain here.  From the Java tutorials:

> For instance, Box is translated to type Box, which is called
>   the raw type — a raw type is a generic class or interface name without
>   any type arguments. This means that you can't find out what type of
>   Object a generic class is using at runtime. The following operations
>   are not possible:
>
> ```
> public class MyClass<E> {
>     public static void myMethod(Object item) {
>         if (item instanceof E) {  //Compiler error
>             ...
>         }
>         E item2 = new E();       //Compiler error
>         E[] iArray = new E[10];  //Compiler error
>         E obj = (E)new Object(); //Unchecked cast warning
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The operations shown in bold are meaningless at runtime because the
>   compiler removes all information about the actual type argument
>   (represented by the type parameter E) at compile time.

With Erasure, the type information is removed, and everything is just an Object:

> When a generic type is instantiated, the compiler translates those
>   types by a technique called type erasure — a process where the
>   compiler removes all information related to type parameters and type
>   arguments within a class or method. Type erasure enables Java
>   applications that use generics to maintain binary compatibility with
>   Java libraries and applications that were created before generics.

Then the compiler re-introduces class "T" as casts everywhere it is required.  T doesn't "exist" inside the generic, so you can't create an object of class T.  On the calls into and out of the generic, the compiler casts the Objects into "T" class.

Google "java erasure" for more information on how this works.  Wikipedia provides [some examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure).

Answer (score 2):

As others said, that's not possible. But since it's a method without arguments and returning void, what would you expect T to be?

Something you might encounter once in a while is this:

```
<T> T foo(Class<T> cls) {
    Object o = ...;
    return cls.cast(o);
}

// usage - perfectly type safe
String s = foo(String.class);
```

Additionally, it's sometimes possible to get generic type arguments, e.g. here:

```
class Foo implements Iterable<String> {
    // snip
}

ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) Foo.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0];
System.out.println(pt); // prints java.lang.Iterable<java.lang.String>

Class<?> at = (Class<?>) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
System.out.println(at.getName()); // prints java.lang.String
```

But that's another story ;)